# User Defined Index for an ArrayList of IDs

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm in a situation where (in Java) I need to define an arraylist of generated ids. I don't know how many would be generated at any given time, but I do know that when one is generated, the user who generated it would need to set a custom index, and be able to retrieve it by that index. What would be the generally accepted standard way of storing and working with a data structure like this? An arraylist of arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which you can use the ID as the key and a value (or potentially an array of values, if multiple values can have the same id) as the value. You can then index into the map and retrieve data using the key. The benefit is that this works even if you want to change the ID from an int to a String or even some other idea.

The problem with using a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) like this is if I have two ids 1 and 3000 then there are 2998 indices that are wasted, which is not exactly ideal.